# How to load distinct items into llblgen pro collection

Tags: c#, llblgenpro, llblgen

I have a collection like the code below. I load all items from table. How to load just distinct items on specific field?

```
 var objlogcollection = new ClsfIcdNineToClsfIcdTenDiagnosisCollection();

 IPredicateExpression filter = new PredicateExpression();
 filter.Add(new FieldCompareValuePredicate(ClsfIcdNineToClsfIcdTenDiagnosisFields.ClsfIcdNineCodeFormatted, ComparisonOperator.NotEqual, ClsfIcdNineToClsfIcdTenDiagnosisFields.ClsfIcdNineCodeFormatted));
 objlogcollection.GetMulti(null);
```

Comment: it might be helpful to post / ask on our own forums, we don't actively monitor stack overflow. LLBLGen Pro already loads unique entities, so I don't really understand what you want as 'distinct items on specific field' is not clear.

Comment: select distinct ClsfField from ClsfData thats what i want to get thank you.

Comment: @FransBouma I thought SO allowed Tag based Subscriptions?

Comment: @Mindaugas so use a linq query, or if you don't want to use linq, use our built-in projection system. THey're both documented in the framework documentation. Fetching 1 field isn't fetching an entity, so the container the data will be placed in should be different, e.g. an anonymous type (linq query) or e.g. a datatable or custom class (projection)

Comment: @JoshuaDrake yes, but our customer support system (HnD) doesn't support this yet, so we can't include a stream of questions in our own system. This will be added this summer.

Comment: can you give me any simple projection sample please? i looked at documentation and its a mess there.